# how can I use string variable instead of using editText1.getText().toString();

Tags: android, android-edittext

such as:

```
String name= editText1.getText().toString();
```

and use this name to getname variable

```
String getname = name;
```

that is write

```
editText1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: post some code cause i doubt anyone got any clue what youre talking about

Comment: but why you required to do so... can you write directly rather that storing in string

Comment: Learn about **Java reflection**.

Comment: Why do you want to make your code more complicated?

Comment: Perhaps if you can, write some background why you want to do this?

Comment: EditText Has Inbuilt Method For Get Text Than Why You Want To Do This?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Java as there isn't any 'eval' method.

You are supposed to use a Map to achieve that:

```
Map<String, EditText> editTextMap = new HashMap<String, EditText>();
editTextMap.put("editText1", findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editTextMap.put("editText2", findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editTextMap.put("editText3", findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

And to call it:

```
editTextMap.get("editText1").getText().toString();
```

Otherwise, you could use reflection but it's a bit harder to read.

Comment: bro hnow do I do this by reflections

Answer (score 1):

As  i am getting this question, the purpose of question is to reduce lines of code to get the string from an edit text.
here is the code i use to get text from all the edit texts in my activity:

```
public String getName(int id){
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(id);
return et.gettext.toString();
}

String Name=getName(R.id.editText1);
```

i am passing id of EditText as argument, and getting text of control in return.

Answer (score 0):

don't make variable, make method. like:

```
String getname(){
   return editText1.getText().toString()
}
```

And use it in:

```
String getname=getname();
```

Comment: I think that the names of Text boxes are generalized so he want that he passes the name of TextBox and it the object corresponding to that name gets into picture.

Comment: You can pass to the function the ID of the EditText, retrieve the component and get the Text. Or you can use Reflection to achieve that.

Comment: bro how do I use reflection

Answer (score 0):

a simple answer would be **no you can't do it**. I don't know you know basic of any OOPS language (C++ , Java, etc) or not but you can consider `editText` as an object which is accessing the methods `getText()` and thus getting the value which is then sent to `toString()` function which converts the send value as a `String`. By using

`String name="editText1."+"getText()."+"toStting()";`

you are simply creating a string that will have value `editText1.getText().toString()`. Thus there is no call of getting the value of `editText` and then converting it to `String` using `toString()`.

P.S. you should read basics of any OOP language before starting android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection:

Method:

```
public <T extends EditText> String value(T field) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{        
    Method method01 = field.getClass().getMethod("getText",  (Class<?>[]) null);

    Editable  editableValue = (Editable)  method01.invoke(field, (Object[]) null);
    String    stringValue   = editableValue.toString();

    return stringValue;
}
```

Using the Method:

```
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value(myEditText), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

EDIT:

If you want use only reflection:

```
public <T extends EditText> String value(T field) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{        
    Method method01 = field.getClass().getMethod("getText",  (Class<?>[]) null);

    Editable  editableValue = (Editable)  method01.invoke(field, (Object[]) null);

    Method method02 = editableValue.getClass().getMethod("toString", (Class<?>[]) null);

    String stringValue = (String) method02.invoke(editableValue, (Object[]) null);

    return stringValue;
}
```